# Choosing Gradle incremental annotation processor category when processor depends on a class in annotation value

Tags: java, gradle, annotation-processing

I have a simple [annotation processor](https://github.com/dimsuz/diff-dispatcher) which is applied like this:

```
@DiffElement(diffReceiver = Renderer.class)
class ViewState {
  String getHello();
  int getWorld();
}

class Renderer {
  void renderHello(String hello);
  void renderWorld(int world);
}
```

For this processor to work, name of `get`-functions and `Renderer`-interface function arguments must match. It checks this and it uses annotation's argument to look at the provided class and do some code generation based on that.

It generates one file.

I have read the docs on [Incremental annotation processing](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:incremental_annotation_processing) and I can't decide which category to apply to this processor. Here are my considerations:

- it can't be `isolating`, because it doesn't derive everything from annotated element's AST, as it also inspects a class from annotation argument
- it can't be `aggregating`, because it doesn't have any annotation on `Renderer` class, so according to the above documentation, processor won't be called whenever `Renderer` class changes, because processor hasn't registered to process this file, so this will lead to errors in generated result.

Questions:

- Do I understand documentation correctly? Or can some category still be applied to this processor
- If it doesn't fall in either category, how can I tell Gradle that it is not incremental, so tools like "kotlin kapt" won't complain to the user that my processor is not incremental

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I understand documentation correctly? Or can some category still be applied to this processor

Documentation on processor categories is really short and, in my opinion, lacks examples. I spent a lot of time figuring out these docs building some simple projects for experiments. So, as far as I know, a category can be applied, if I did figure them out correctly in the end :)

You say that

> it can't be isolating, because it doesn't derive everything from annotated element's AST, as it also inspects a class from annotation argument

This is not exactly right and I'll explain why.
As mentioned in [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#isolating_annotation_processors), isolating processors

> must make all decisions (code generation, validation messages) for an annotated type based on information reachable from its AST. This means you can analyze the types' super-class, method return types, annotations etc., even transitively.

"Even transitively" phrase is very important here - it means, that you can analyse not only annotated type's AST, but, for example, some of it's method's return type's AST as well, and then, let's say, a superclass of that type...

As I understand it, **every type, that you can discover via AST walks from the annotated element, is a dependency of the annotated type** (or element in general). And if a dependency is changed, then the depending type needs recompilation. So when `Renderer` class changes, `ViewState` **will be recompiled** and thus reprocessed, because **it references** `Renderer` **as its annotation argument**. Supertypes, superinterfaces, methods' return types, method parameters' types, annotation class arguments, ... - all these are considered dependent types.

So, your annotation processor actually can be **isolating**.

---

*P.S.* If isolating doesn't work, ensure that annotation retention is `CLASS` or higher, for whatever reason.

*P.P.S.* I find incrementality in annotation processing a really shady topic, full of surprises and underwater rocks. The rule of thumb I discovered for myself is that practically every processor with a few tweaks can be isolating, unless it really needs to generate one entity based on many inputs. And, what's important, only if these inputs can be completely unrelated to each other in terms of references or even be in a different libraries.

Comment: Thank your for such detailed analysis! I have changed the accepted answer to be yours, because it answers my question directly (while the previous answer by Colin was helpful too).

Answer (score 0):

> it can't be aggregating, because it doesn't have any annotation on Renderer class, so according to the above documentation, processor won't be called whenever Renderer class changes, because processor hasn't registered to process this file, so this will lead to errors in generated result.

This isn't going to be a direct answer, but I think it may still answer your question: This statement, as I understand it, is the actual source of your problem. Any mildly incremental system is going to fail you here, not just Gradle's "aggregating" mode (try using your processor in a simple Eclipse project, for example, and possibly even IntelliJ, though I've had mixed results there).

If you actually want to enforce that changes to an un-annotated type will cause your annotation processor to run again, you must not limit your annotation processor to that annotation, but must return the magic `"*"` value from `getSupportedAnnotationTypes()`, indicating that any changed class must trigger the processor to re-run. [From the Javadoc for this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html#getSupportedAnnotationTypes--):

> Finally, "*" by itself represents the set of all annotation types, including the empty set. Note that a processor should not claim "*" unless it is actually processing all files; claiming unnecessary annotations may cause a performance slowdown in some environments.

Ideally, you would just make a second (or third, etc) annotation to provide this hint instead, but that isn't always feasible, which is why you're allowed this wildcard option

Comment: I suspected that I will have to restructure my processor and add an extra annotation to correctly track changes to annotated classes. I didn't know about `"*"` option, but I'm afraid it would be an overkill. I will try to rethink annotation structure I suppose. Thank you!

Comment: Certainly overkill, but can still be worth it if you have a way to provide a gradle project just for these types, so that it makes good sense to re-run the processor for any changes.